# Two way binding with a DataGrid vs. a ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid

I'm having trouble understanding a discrepancy in the handling of two-way binding between a DataGrid vs. a ListView.  To illustrate, I have a class DataItem with a few properties, and a List of DataItems for binding to the DataGrid/ListView:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    public List<DataItem> SubList { get; set; }

    public DataItem()[...]

}
```

I create a main DataItem object with a number of additional DataItem objects adde into the SubList.  The main DataItem is set to the DataContext of a containing Grid, and the SubList is bound to both a ListView:

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubList}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Flag" Width="Auto">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Name="FlagCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Flag}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="String Value" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Name="StringTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=StringValue}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

and to a DataGrid:

```
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Flag" Width="SizeToCells">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Name="FlagCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Flag}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="String Value" Width="SizeToCells">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="StringTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=StringValue}" /> 
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Both the ListView and the DataGrid properly display the SubList items.  However, when I modify the data in the UI, and examine the source DataItem.SubList, the ListView works and the DataGrid doesn't: I can see the changes when they are made in the ListView, but when the changes are made in the DataGrid, there are no changes.

The bindings must be correct, otherwise I wouldn't see the values displayed properly.  But for some reason, two-way binding works in the ListView to move changes made in the UI back to the source object, but not in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` to propagate changes back to your DataObject class in case of DataGrid.

```
<CheckBox Name="FlagCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Flag, 
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And on TextBox too -

```
<TextBox Name="StringTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=StringValue, 
                                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it works.  Odd that the default setting for UpdateSourceTrigger is to not update the source.